Magento 2 Is there any extension for Binance payment gateway or how to integrate with magento 2?
I want to implement Binance Payment gateway to Magento 2 How can I do this, and if there is any extension for this? Thanks in advance.

Currently the following module is available to integrate with Binance Payment. So installing and configuring it with the readme should be no issue. Still it declares that needs RabbitMQ for background processing (which usually is not installed and configured). So, you might need to review and configure that into your install to make it work. DevOps work might be required here.
The only element to take into consideration is that Binance Payments does not have sandbox environment for testing, so you might need to have 2 accounts for testing this.
Also as webhooks are involved here you might need to have your testing environment reachable from internet for the webhooks to work. If that's not possible, you can try using some utility like ngrok

This is not working with the local environment. i have to check at least once before adding it to the server

Make sure you have rabbitmq working on the local environment and you are running the correct command as explanied here

Also, as this make usage of webhooks, your computer should be accesible from the internet to work as expected. If you don't have the computer open to the word, you can try using a ssh tunnel to accomplish the same thing.
